# Using PayPal Do Direct Payment recieving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am using the test application and has updated my Username and Password but sending me error as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security>
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
        <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
            <Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username>
            <Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password>
            <Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature>
            <Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject>
        </Credentials>
    </RequesterCredentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
    <DoDirectPaymentResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
        <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2017-07-11T12:39:40Z</Timestamp>
        <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack>
        <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">5a971b576472c</CorrelationID>
        <Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType">
            <ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Authentication/Authorization Failed</ShortMessage>
            <LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">You do not have permissions to make this API call</LongMessage>
            <ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">10002</ErrorCode>
            <SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Error</SeverityCode>
        </Errors>
        <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">117.0</Version>
        <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">33063964</Build>
    </DoDirectPaymentResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

IN my congiguration file I have set as

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAcctAndConfig()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> configMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        configMap = GetConfig();

        // Signature Credential
        configMap.Add("account1.apiUsername", "XXXXXX-XXXXXXXX_XXX.XXXXXXX.com");
        configMap.Add("account1.apiPassword", "XXXXXXXXX");
        configMap.Add("account1.apiSignature", "XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXx-XXXXXXXXX");
        // Optional
        configMap.Add("account1.subject", "testSubject");
        return configMap;
    }
```

I have also checked for below path and all sets to be fine
https://help.tictail.com/hc/en-us/articles/205660201-PayPal-error-You-do-not-have-permissions-to-make-this-API-call-

**Can any one get me how should I resolve my issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Please comment out the line of

```
configMap.Add("account1.subject", "testSubject");
```

from configuration file and try your test again.